# Unitarity of $e^{-it\Delta }$ as a map on Sobolev spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, spectral-theory

I am looking for an argument or reference proving that for $s>0$
$$
\| e^{-i\Delta t}\psi\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)}=\|\psi\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)}
$$
where $e^{-i\Delta t}$ is the solution map for the time dependent (free) Schrödinger equation,
$$
i\partial_t\psi=\Delta\psi,
$$
defined via the functional calculus.

This was mentioned in a talk I attended and I am sure it is a standard fact, but I haven't found a suitable reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|e^{-it|\xi|^2}|=1,$ it follows that

$$\|e^{-i\Delta t}\psi\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}_x^d)}=\|\langle \xi\rangle^s e^{-it|\xi|^2}\hat{\psi}\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}_\xi^d)}=\|\langle \xi\rangle^s \hat{\psi}\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}_\xi^d)}=\|\psi\|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}_x^d)}.$$

Comment: Whoops, typo fixed

Comment: wow I feel silly. thank you, this is perfect.